# How do I restrict GCP load balancer access by domain, domain's IP or GKE ingress IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have assets in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I created a subdomain (aaa.bbb.com) and a load balancer using that subdomain to point to that bucket (e.g. `aaa.bbb.com/image-to-read.png`). I also have an application using Google Kubernetes Engine. The goal is to make sure all users are blocked except that application on GKE. And all the GKE application is doing is reading the url of the assets to display them. How do I achieve that?

Things I've tried:

1. **Setting GCS cors for the bucket**

   It turns out this only restricts by domain if people are signed into Google with the domain.
2. **Workload Identity**

   This has just not worked for me. I also have an API service in the same GKE cluster that uses this and I'm able to upload fine with it. However, using a plain `<img />` tag with the source as a the GCS bucket ignores the Workload Identity as far as I can tell.
3. **Cloud Armor**

   This seems the most promising. I have successfully restricted by IP address but, unfortunately, the only IP address I'm able to restrict by is my actual local computer. I believe that means the request headers are sending my computer's IP address to the load balancer. But what I am trying to do is restrict access by the application's load balancer IP address or even by the origin domain (preferred).

What I'm asking is probably a basic networking question, but I'm no wiz at all the devops/infrastructure concepts so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Cloud Storage authorization
- Deploy an HTTP(S) Load Balancer + Cloud Armor.

I am not sure what you mean by GKE ingress IP.

The simplest is to add Authorization in your GKE application when accessing Cloud Storage.

Authorization:

- Service Account OAuth Access Token
- Signed URLs.

Both methods are easy to implement.

Note: Workload Identity Federation also generates service account OAuth access tokens. Use that method if need to federate credentials from one OAuth Authority to Google. However, for a GKE application, Signed URLs or service account OAuth access tokens are probably the correct solution.

Comment: For Cloud Storage Authorization, would that be for actual users? And I'm currently trying the load balancer + Cloud Armor. What I'm confused about is how to only allow the application to read the assets. The application is a docker image in GKE, and I've enabled an ingress for it to allow the internet to access it via its IP address. How do I specify that I only want the application to read assets from storage without making the access public?

Comment: @MartavisP. - 1/2) Your question states **all users are blocked except that application on GKE**. I need more details on the application and how users are accessing storage. I assumed that your application is accessing cloud storage.

Comment: @MartavisP. - 2/2)  If the users are directly accessing cloud storage, then use Signed URLs or OAuth. Remember that the HTTP Load Balancer is public. You can use Cloud Armor rules to start restricting that traffic via IP address, hostname, origin, etc. However, you need well-defined rules to control which users can access. In summary, you need to specify what and how cloud storage is being accessed and by what/whom.

Comment: The application allows users to view images and videos. Although the users have logins to the application, they **are not** logging in via OAuth using Google. If the user goes to a page, the page contains the Storage URLs for all the images and videos to be displayed (e.g. aaa.bbb.com/image-to-see.png). That's why I'm trying to restrict access at the application level. Does that help?

Comment: @MartavisP. - Then your only real option is Signed URLs. If your users are not using authorization (Google OAuth, secret key in an HTTP header, etc), then they are public and there is very little for you to firewall using Cloud Armor. Your backend application will generate the page of URLs.  That page will consist of Signed URLs. Also, make your Cloud Storage Bucket non-public.

Comment: @MartavisP. - You might see suggestions/articles about using CORS and origin headers. However, CORS is enforced by the web browser and not Cloud Storage. I can bypass CORS in seconds.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help. I will look into Signed URLs.